# Samsung Note 8 GT-N5110 restarts by itself

Tags: samsung, tablet

My Note 8 (stock android 4.4.2) worked perfectly until one day it decided that it would restart by itself every time after I shut it down. To make a long story short, if I reset the device to the factory settings and leave the battery disconnected for a few days the table will work fine after reconnecting the battery. However, if I connect the device to the internet it updates untold thousands of applications and the problem reappears. I have repeated this process about four times and have concluded that there is an update that is causing the problem, but have no idea of how to identify the problem application(s). I have also decided that there are applications like Allshare Controlshare Service that will update themselves once they see the internet even if you tell the device not to update anything. They will also reinstall the update even if you roll it back to the factory default. I would appreciate any ideas on how to safely reconnect this tablet to the internet.

Comment: All I can say is that your device has been hit by malwares! You can't get rid of them by simply resetting your device, they're installee as system apps. What you need to do now is to flash the device with a clean firmware then everything should be back to the normal

Answer (score 0):

Following esQmo's suggestion, I followed the general instructions given at
[Install Original Factory Rom on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9A71XhERjbE) and reinstalled the stock firmware. Never did anything like that before, but to my surprise it worked and the tablet now is behaving itself.